# Magento2 data migration Map Step error

Tags: magento2, data-migration, data-migration-tool

While migrate the data from Magento 1.14.2.2 to Magento 2.2.3, I'm getting the below error.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Migration\Step\Map\Data::getRecordTransformer() must be an instance of Migration\ResourceModel\Document, boolean given, called in /var/www/html/magentoroot/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/src/Migration/Step/Map/Data.php on line 147
```

Please any suggestion the solutions

Answer (score 0):

add below code before line 147 in vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/src/Migration/Step/Map/Data.php file and check for which table has problem and try to solve it accordingly.

```
echo $sourceDocName;
```